# If $A$ is a bounded matrix-valued function, is the map $x \mapsto A(x)x$ Lipschitz?

Tags: real-analysis, matrices, lipschitz-functions

Let $A \colon \mathbb{R}^{m} \to \mathbb{R}^{m\times m}$ be a given matrix-valued function, and suppose that all its entries are smooth *bounded* functions $\mathbb{R}^{m} \to \mathbb{R}$. Does this imply that the map

$$
\begin{align}
F \colon \mathbb{R}^{m} &\to \mathbb{R}^{m}\\
x &\mapsto A(x)x
\end{align}
$$
is globally Lipschitz?

Comment: Lipschitz in the sense that there is a $\lambda$ such that $\frac{\|A(y)y-A(x)x\|}{\|y-x\|}<\lambda$ for all $x,y\in\mathbb{R}^m$?

Comment: Yep, that's what I need.

Comment: Than smoothness and boundedness is certainly not sufficient; consider $A(x)$ a rotation by an angle of $\|x\|^2$.

Comment: I see, thank you. Then what could be a sufficient condition on $A$ which guarantees globally Lipschitz continuity? As a matter of fact, the specific matrix $A$ I am dealing with is skew-symmetric. Would that be of any help?

Comment: It seems like some kind of "falloff condition" would be needed, ensuring that the $dA/dx$ decreases to zero "sufficiently quickly" as $\|x\|\to\infty$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Take $m = 1$ and $A(x) = \sin(x)$ so that $F(x) = \sin(x) \cdot x$. If you assume that $F$ is globally Lipschitz, then there exists $M > 0$ so that

$$ |F(x) - F(y)| \leq M|x - y| $$

for all $x,y \in \mathbb{R}$. Taking $x = 2\pi k + \varepsilon$ and $y = 2\pi k$ for $\varepsilon \neq 0$ and $k \in \mathbb{N}$ we get

$$ |F(x) - F(y)| = |(\varepsilon + 2\pi k) \sin (\varepsilon)| \leq M |\varepsilon| $$

which implies that

$$ \left| \frac{\sin(\varepsilon)}{\varepsilon} \right| \leq \frac{M}{|\varepsilon + 2\pi k|}. $$

Taking $\varepsilon \to 0$ we get

$$ 1 \leq \frac{M}{2\pi k} \iff 2\pi k \leq M $$

for all $k \in \mathbb{N}$, a contradiction.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Would assuming $m >1$ and $A$ skew-symmetric change anything?

Comment: @MK7: No. You can take say $m = 2$ and $A(x,y) = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & -\sin(x) \cos(y) \\ \sin(x) \cos(y) & 0 \end{pmatrix}$ and then $F(x,0) = (0, \sin(x) \cdot x)$ and again you run into the same problem.